# Custom choices in WTForms SelectField bsed on current date

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I would like to create a custom `SelectField` that provides different choices in based on the current date.  For example, if it is the 13th of the month, the choices will be the values 1 through 13.  How do I do this?

```
def register_extensions(app):
    security.init_app(app, datastore=ds, register_form=forms.ExtendedRegisterForm)

class ExtendedRegisterForm(RegisterForm):
    pay_month = SelectField(choices=[('need', 'custom'), ('day', 'choices')])
```

Comment: Figured out a easier way to do this: pay_month = SelectField('2nd Pay Day of Month', choices=[(idx, dt) for idx, dt in enumerate((datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=y)).date().strftime('%B-%d') for y in range(datetime.datetime.today().day))])

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Override the form's `__init__` method and populate the field's `choices` with the range of values from 1 to the current day.

```
from datetime import datetime

class ExtendedRegisterForm(RegisterForm):
    pay_month = SelectField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ExtendedRegsiterForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        now = datetime.utcnow()
        self.pay_month.choices = [(i, i) for i in range(1, now.day + 1)]
```